# Using automapper with datetime and bool to represent a half day in POCO

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, automapper

Say I have a POCO that stores a date range as follows:

```
public class DateRange()
{
public DateTime FromDate{get;set;}
public DateTime ToDate{get;set;}
}
```

I want to be able to save a half day at the beginning and/or end of the range. To do this I'm going to present my data as a jqueryui date picker for a from date and to date as well as a checkbox next to each datepicker to represent a 1/2 day. My viewmodel would look something like this:

```
public class DateRangeModel()
{
public DateTime FromDate {get; set;}
public DateTime ToDate{get;set;}
public bool IsFromDateHalfDay{get; set;}
public bool IsToDateHalfDay {get; set;}
}
```

When the 1/2 day checkbox is checked for the FromDate I need to save the FromDate in the entity as the selected day + 12 hours and when the 1/2 day checkbox is selected for the ToDate in the ViewModel I need to save the ToDate in the entity as the selected day + 12 hours.

Is it possible to do this using Automapper? If not could you suggest a better/different approach? I dont want to have the bools representing the half-days in the entity because I want to use the DateTimes alone for calculations.

Some Examples (Still contemplating how i should represent a range of 1 day and 1/2 a day - going to need to test calculating ranges a lot!):

```
A Date Range of 1/2 Day From 24th May to a full day 27th May:
2011-05-24 12:00:00.000 => 2011-05-28 00:00:00.000

A Date Range of Full Day From 24th May to a 1/2 day 27th May:
2011-05-24 00:00:00.000 => 2011-05-27 12:00:00.000

A Half Day on 24th May:
2011-05-24 12:00:00.000 => 2011-05-25 00:00:00.000     

A Full Day on 24th May:
2011-05-24 12:00:00.000 > 2011-05-25 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: After a quick read, it seems like you might be better off storing a starting DateTime and a TimeSpan length.  Something to consider at least.

Comment: yep this has definitely got me thinking about the best way to store the range! i'm going to need to represent the span on a calendar and save the number of days and business days in the span etc

Comment: this lead me to ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355316/storing-a-timespan-between-two-datetimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we to assume the FromDate/ToDate can only be Full Days (12:00 AM) or Half Days (12:00 PM)?

**Domain to View (if needed):**

```
CreateMap<DateRange, DateRangeModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsFromDateHalfDay, opts => opts.MapFrom(src=>src.FromDate.Hour == 12))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsToDateHalfDay, opts => opts.MapFrom(src=>src.ToDate.Hour == 12));
```

**View to Domain**

```
CreateMap<DateRangeModel, DateRange>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FromDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(src=>src.FromDate.AddHours(-1 * src.IsFromDateHalfDay ? 12 : 0))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ToDate, opts => opts.MapFrom(src=>src.ToDate.AddHours(src.IsToDateHalfDay ? 12 : 0));
```

Comment: Yep ToDate/FromDate can only be 1/2 or full days. Ill edit the question to describe how I need the DateTimes represented :)

Answer (score 2):

Jimmy Bogard talks about doing something similar here: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/06/automapper-feature-custom-type-converters/

The principle is that you'd create a custom mapping. At the point of mapping, you'd take the two booleans into account, however they would not feature in the target type.